# How do I get get-childitem to filter on multiple file types?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get a list of all the XSL and XSLT files in a directory.

```
dir -recurse -filter *.xsl,*.xslt -name
```

But the following error:

> Get-ChildItem : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Filter'. Specified method is not supported.

```
dir -recurse -filter *.xsl -filter *.xslt -name
```

But got this error:

> Get-ChildItem : Cannot bind parameter because parameter 'Filter' is specified more than once. To provide multiple values to parameters that can accept multiple values, use the array syntax. For example, "-parameter value1,value2,value3".

Can I list both file extensions with a single command?

Comment: [How to properly -filter multiple strings in a PowerShell copy script](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18626464/1366033)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```
dir .\* -include ('*.xsl', '*.xslt') -recurse
```

Comment: Note that the () is actually redundant, but I prefer to be explicit.

Comment: It makes absolutely no sense why this command does not work without the -recurse switch, to list .xsl and .xslt files in the current directory.

Comment: the answer by crysman is faster https://superuser.com/a/1056648/440382

Answer (score 34):

I do not know why, but this one seems to be **much faster**:

```
dir .\ -recurse | where {$_.extension -in ".xsl",".xslt"}
```

Comment: because `-include` is slow - https://stackoverflow.com/a/52294304/16391

Answer (score 13):

The "filters" `*.xsl` and `*.xslt` can be part of the path parameter as well. Path *can* take a string array:

```
Set-Location c:\topLevel
gci *.xsl, *.xslt -Recurse
```

If you want to specify a path other than the current location, or search multiple locations, create a couple of string arrays and use [`Join-Path`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path?view=powershell-7.2) to create an array of paths:

```
PS C:\> $paths   = 'c:\topLevel' , 'd:\topLevel'
PS C:\> $filters = '*.xsl' , '*.xslt'
PS C:\> $filters | ForEach-Object { Join-Path $paths $_ }
c:\topLevel\*.xsl
d:\topLevel\*.xsl
c:\topLevel\*.xslt
d:\topLevel\*.xslt
PS C:\>
```

That output can be piped to Get-ChildItem:

```
$paths   = 'c:\topLevel' , 'd:\topLevel'
$filters = '*.xsl' , '*.xslt'
$filters | % { Join-Path $paths $_ } | gci -name
```

### Bonus Tip:

If you don't need the additional properties of the FileInfo objects, but just a list of fully qualifed paths, [`Resolve-Path`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/resolve-path?view=powershell-7.2) is faster:

```
$paths   = 'c:\topLevel' , 'd:\topLevel'
$filters = '*.xsl' , '*.xslt'
$filters | % { Join-Path $paths $_ } | Resolve-Path
```

MY quick test:

```
PS C:\>Measure-Command { $filters | % { Join-Path $path $_ } | gci | select -expand FullName }

...
TotalMilliseconds : 31.2376



PS C:\>Measure-Command { $filters | % { Join-Path $path $_ } | Resolve-Path }

...
TotalMilliseconds : 12.2536
```

Answer (score 2):

The question:
'I'm trying to get a list of all the XSL and XSLT files in a directory.'

This is a simpler approach:

```
Get-ChildItem * -Recurse -File | Where-Object { $_.Name -like "*.XSL*" }
```

which will get all .xsl and .xslt files.

Additionally, you can add ' -OR ( $_.Name -like "search string" ) inside the braces if you wanted to look for two different strings at the same time, like so:

```
Get-ChildItem * -Recurse -File | Where-Object { ($_.Name -like "string 1") -OR ( $_.Name -like "string 2") }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is older, but it helped me write this script to update URL's in desktop and/or favorite shortcuts, so I thought I would share:

```
foreach ($link in GCI "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop" | Where-Object {$_.extension -in '.lnk','.url'}) {
   $shell = New-Object -COM WScript.Shell
   $shortcut = $shell.CreateShortcut($link.FullName)
   $shortcut.TargetPath = $shortcut.TargetPath -replace "old-url.com","new-url.com"
   $shortcut.Save()
}
```

```
foreach ($link in GCI "$env:USERPROFILE\Favorites" | Where-Object {$_.extension -in '.lnk','.url'}) {
   $shell = New-Object -COM WScript.Shell
   $shortcut = $shell.CreateShortcut($link.FullName)
   $shortcut.TargetPath = $shortcut.TargetPath -replace "old-url.com","new-url.com"
   $shortcut.Save()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question and I wanted to avoid using any -Include or -Recurse:

```
# Declare your base/common path:
$Path = 'C:\Xpto\123'

# Because -Filter will not accept a list, create a list
# that contains all the variations you need, and instead
# provide the list to -Path.
# Note: Requires double quotes instead of single:
$FileSpecs = ForEach-Object{$($Path + "\*.flac"), $($Path + "\*.dsf")}

Get-ChildItem -Path $FileSpecs

# In case you want to use a single line of commands:
'C:\Xpto\123' | ForEach-Object{$($_ + "\*.flac"), $($_ + "\*.dsf")} | Get-ChildItem
```