# Get-Childitem -Include array seperator

Tags: powershell

That don't work for me, why? What is here the right seperator?

The idea is from this question:
[How do I get get-childitem to filter on multiple file types?](https://superuser.com/questions/318197/how-do-i-get-get-childitem-to-filter-on-multiple-file-types/1097927)

```
$Jetzt = Get-Date
$Alterung = "14"
$Cache = "D:\SCANS\"
$Aenderung = $Jetzt.AddDays(-$Alterung)
$Files = Get-Childitem $Cache -Force -Include ('*.docx', '*.pdf') | Where {$_.LastWriteTime -le "$Aenderung"}
""
"Alle Dateien aelter als $Alterung_DIR Tage werden geloescht."
""
foreach ($File in $Files)
{
    if ($File -ne $NULL)
    {
            "Am $Jetzt GELOESCHT--> $File"
            Remove-Item $File.FullName -Force -recurse | out-NULL
    }
    else
    {
        "Keine Datei geloescht!"
    }
}

""
"Skriptende"
```

The Output is:

```
Alle Dateien aelter als 14 Tage werden geloescht.

Keine Datei geloescht!

Skriptende
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things to fix here.

1. The `-Include` parameter requires that you also use the `-Path` parameter.
   From `Get-Help Get-ChildItem -full`,

> "The value of this parameter qualifies the Path parameter. Enter a path element or pattern, such as '*.txt'. Wildcards are permitted."

2. `$Cache` should end with an asterisk. More from `Get-Help Get-ChildItem -full`,

> "The Include parameter is effective only when the command includes the
>   Recurse parameter or the path leads to the contents of a directory,
>   such as C:\Windows*, where the wildcard character specifies the
>   contents of the C:\Windows directory."

3. You do not need parenthesis or single quotes around these extensions since they do not contain any spaces or special characters.

Your changes should be,

```
$Files = Get-Childitem -Path $Cache -Force -Include *.docx, *.pdf
$Cache = "D:\SCANS\*"
```

Unrelated, but it may also be preferable to replace `if ($File -ne $NULL)` with `if (!$File)`.