# List of images exceeding 4M pixels with Powershell

Tags: powershell, images

I have folder with multiple image files and I want details of only three different formats (jpeg, png and gif). I need to find the images that are exceeding 4 million pixels, so the width multiplied by height can't exceed 4 million pixels. Basically, I just need a list of images that are exceeding the limit and possibly showing the total pixel amount. Is there a way to do it with Powershell? Feel free to recommend some other programs that are able to do this.

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13741668/get-list-of-image-files-with-specific-dimensions-as-file-objects-using-powershel) and edited it a bit for my purposes:

```py
Add-Type -Assembly System.Drawing

function Get-Image { 
process {
          $file = $_
          [Drawing.Image]::FromFile($_.FullName) |
          ForEach-Object {           
            $_ | Add-Member -PassThru NoteProperty FullName ('{0}' -f $file.FullName)
          }
         }
}

Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\imagefolder' -Filter *.jpg -Recurse | Get-Image | ? { ($_.Width * $_.Height) -gt 4000000 } | select -expa Fullname | get-item
```

Now, I receive a list of jpg images that exceed the 4-million pixel limit.
If I don't use the filter, it goes through all the files in the folder and throws an error for all the non-image files. This is not actually a big problem but would be nice to check only jpg, png and gif files.

Also, I'm still not able to see the total pixel size of the image and not really know how to do that.

Comment: What have you tried so far? We aren't a script writing service.

Comment: That's the problem that I'm not familiar with Powershell. Of course, I'm able to google the Powershell commands and similar questions from StackExchange but didn't find anything that would solve my problem. I know it's possible to get the image width and height but I'm not able to put the pieces together. Would be just embarrassing to show what I have tried so far, hehe.

Comment: Please show what you have tried. You're asking us to put forth effort when you are unwilling to show the effort you've given yourself. Your problem is relatively simple: you need to go through a list of files, multiply the width and height pixel values, and flag those over a certain value. So, what have you tried?

Comment: I have now added an example what I have tried so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you want to select your file types as explained in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/318197/how-do-i-get-get-childitem-to-filter-on-multiple-file-types) so you would want something like this using `-Include` rather than `-Filter`

`Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\imagefolder' -Include('*.jpg','*.png','.gif') -Recurse`

From these you want to select only those over 4 million pixels.  You can use the `Get-Image` function in your question - if you `Select *` on its output you can see what it gives you.

```
PS C:\> Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\imagefolder' -Include('*.jpg','*.png','.gif') -Recurse | Get-Image | Select *


FullName             : C:\imagefolder\DSC00237.JPG
Tag                  :
PhysicalDimension    : {Width=5152, Height=3864}
Size                 : {Width=5152, Height=3864}
Width                : 5152
Height               : 3864
HorizontalResolution : 350
VerticalResolution   : 350
Flags                : 77840
RawFormat            : [ImageFormat: b96b3cae-0728-11d3-9d7b-0000f81ef32e]
PixelFormat          : Format24bppRgb
Palette              : System.Drawing.Imaging.ColorPalette
FrameDimensionsList  : {7462dc86-6180-4c7e-8e3f-ee7333a7a483}
PropertyIdList       : {270, 271, 272, 274...}
PropertyItems        : {270, 271, 272, 274...}
```

So you see it has the `Width` and `Height` so (as in your question) you can work out number of pixels by multiplying and then select only those objects where this number is greater than 4m with `Where { ($_.Width * $_.Height) -gt 4000000 }`

Finally you want to `Select` what to display from the available properties.  You can rename calculated fields as described [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-change-output-object-property-names-with-powershell/) so for name and pixels you would want to `Select Fullname, @{N='Pixels'; E={ ($_.Width * $_.Height) }}` to give

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\imagefolder' -Include('*.jpg','*.png','.gif') -Recurse | `
Get-Image | Where { ($_.Width * $_.Height) -gt 4000000 } | `
Select Fullname, @{N='Pixels'; E={ ($_.Width * $_.Height) }}
```

After changing the path and number of pixels this gives output like this :

```
PS D:\> Add-Type -Assembly System.Drawing
PS D:\> function Get-Image{
>> process {
>>           $file = $_
>>           [Drawing.Image]::FromFile($_.FullName)  |
>>           ForEach-Object{
>>             $_ | Add-Member -PassThru NoteProperty FullName ('{0}' -f $file.FullName)
>>           }
>>          }
>> }
PS D:\> Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Hali\OneDrive\Pictures\2004' -Include('*.jpg','*.png','.gif') -Recurse | Get-Image | Where { ($_.Width * $_.Height) -gt 100000 } | Select Fullname, @{N='Pixels'; E={ ($_.Width * $_.Height)  }}    
FullName                                                                  Pixels
--------                                                                  ------
D:\Hali\OneDrive\Pictures\2004\06\PICT0262 (2014_05_15 20_48_01 UTC).jpg 5038848
D:\Hali\OneDrive\Pictures\2004\06\PICT0264 (2014_05_15 20_48_01 UTC).jpg 5038848
D:\Hali\OneDrive\Pictures\2004\06\PICT0265 (2014_05_15 20_48_01 UTC).jpg 5038848
D:\Hali\OneDrive\Pictures\2004\06\PICT0266 (2014_05_15 20_48_01 UTC).jpg 5038848
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script is pretty much complete. You're already filtering. Though [`Get-ChildItem`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-6) only supports a single filter. But later on you're already using [`Where-Object`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-6) with its shorthand (`?{}`). Just do that after the `Get-ChildItem` and filter for the extension. You can get information about objects using [`Get-Member`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member?view=powershell-6).

Figure out what attributes contain the extension e.g. by running `Get-ChildItem example.jpg | Get-Member` and use that attribute in a `Where-Object` to filter it.