# Get-ChildItem vs GetFiles vs EnumerateFiles vs EnumerateFileSystemEntries (Which is Best?)

Tags: powershell-core

I am attempting to determine the most efficient method of populating a string array with file paths recursively from a given folder. Only the file paths are needed and; although not required, it would be an added bonus if I can do work on the resulting files as their paths are discovered. I am using PowerShell Version 7.3.6 on Windows 10, and have one or more file extensions to search for in a folder with many sub-folders and many other file types. I happened upon the questions presented at the links below and attempted to partially or fully implement each of the suggested solutions. This post is quite long because I wanted to leave as little as possible to speculation. I am seeking feedback regarding how to improve the performance of the code snippets included in this post and suggestions for any other methods that might yield more efficient (timely) results.

[How do I get get-childitem to filter on multiple file types?](https://superuser.com/questions/318197/how-do-i-get-get-childitem-to-filter-on-multiple-file-types)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970692/powershell-io-directory-find-file-types-in-all-subdirectories

It is abundantly clear that the Get-ChildItem -Filter parameter does not accept multiple criterion, which is a requirement in my use case. Therefore, one potential solution is Get-ChildItem with the -Include and -Exclude parameters, which has been implemented as follows:

```
[string]$SourcePath = "H:\Duplicate File Work\"
[string[]]$IncludeFilter = $null
[string[]]$FilePathCollection = $null
$IncludeFilter += "*.doc"
$IncludeFilter += "*.xls"
$IncludeFilter += "*.ppt"

$StopWatch = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::New()
$StopWatch.Start()

$FilePathCollection = Get-ChildItem -Path $SourcePath -Include $IncludeFilter -Recurse

Write-Host $FilePathCollection.Count

$StopWatch.Stop()
$StopWatch.Elapsed
```

The above code produced 22,853 results in roughly 4 minutes:27 seconds and did not allow me to do work on each file as they were discovered because the string array must be fully populated by Get-ChildItem before it can be used. Another potential solution is GetFiles, which has been implemented as follows:

```
[string]$SourcePath = "H:\Duplicate File Work\"
[string[]]$IncludeFilter = $null
[string[]]$FilePathCollection = $null
$IncludeFilter += "*.doc"
$IncludeFilter += "*.xls"
$IncludeFilter += "*.ppt"

$StopWatch = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::New()
$StopWatch.Start()

foreach ($Filter in $IncludeFilter) {
    foreach ($File in [IO.Directory]::GetFiles($SourcePath, $Filter, "AllDirectories")) {
        $FileAttributes = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $File).Attributes -split ", "
        if ($FileAttributes -match "Hidden") {
            Continue
        }
        else {
            $FilePathCollection += $File
        }
    }
}
Write-Host $FilePathCollection.Count

$StopWatch.Stop()
$StopWatch.Elapsed
```

The above code produced 22,853 results; the same number as Get-ChildItem, in roughly 6 minutes:6 seconds and allowed me to do work on each file as they were discovered. Note the addition of an if/else block to allow filtering of hidden files as they are discovered. EnumerateFiles and EnumerateFileSystemEntries produced the same results count as GetFiles at 6 minutes:49 seconds and 6 minutes:42 seconds respectively. Get-ChildItem did not find hidden files like GetFiles, EnumerateFiles, and EnumerateFileSystemEntries did. The obvious choice in terms of efficiency (timeliness) appears to be Get-ChildItem; however, this method does not allow work to be done on files as they are discovered. To be sure that the 22,853 files found by Get-ChildItem and GetFiles are the same 22,853 files, the following code was used:

```
[string]$SourcePath = "H:\Duplicate File Work\"
[string[]]$IncludeFilter = $null
[string[]]$FilePathCollection1 = $null
[string[]]$FilePathCollection2 = $null
[system.object]$CompareObjects = $null
[system.object]$StopWatch = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::New()
$IncludeFilter += "*.doc"
$IncludeFilter += "*.xls"
$IncludeFilter += "*.ppt"

$StopWatch.Start()

foreach ($Filter in $IncludeFilter) {
    foreach ($File in [IO.Directory]::GetFiles($SourcePath, $Filter, "AllDirectories")) {
        $FileAttributes = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $File).Attributes -split ", "
        if ($FileAttributes -match "Hidden") {
            Continue
        }
        else {
            $FilePathCollection1 += $File
        }
    }
}
Write-Host $FilePathCollection1.Count

$StopWatch.Stop()
$StopWatch.Elapsed

$StopWatch.Reset()
$StopWatch.Start()

foreach ($File in Get-ChildItem -Path $SourcePath -Include $IncludeFilter -Recurse) {
    $FilePathCollection2 += $File
}
Write-Host $FilePathCollection2.Count

$StopWatch.Stop()
$StopWatch.Elapsed

$CompareObjects = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $FilePathCollection1 -DifferenceObject $FilePathCollection2
$CompareObjects | Out-GridView
```

Examination of Compare-Object results (none) yielded no differences between the files found by Get-ChildItem and those found by GetFiles. Viola!

Now back to the original intent of this post's question. Are there any other methods to achieve the stated goal with more efficiency or ways to improve the efficiency of one or more of the given methods?

Comment: So this will not answer your question but might give you a clue.  Under the hood, this is calling the FindFirstFile() Win32 API function.  It does not take multiple filters.  Only one.  This means that the .net wrapper for this function needs to process each return in a subroutine.  .Net code can be optimized by the compiler in ways your code will not.  I am not saying PowerShell isn't optimized by JIT.  I am saying not as well and you are probably not going to write code as efficiently as the .net developer that wrote the original in c#/MSIL (which is what it is using).  Just a guess.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas - I appreciate the insight. I assume that the gist of your comment is applicable to Get-ChildItem. I agree that I will not likely exceed the achievements of .NET developers. Would you suggest using GetFiles instead? Do you have any other more suggestions that might be more efficient?

Comment: I am sorry @Don.. when I get to this point, I just go to Win32/C .. I haven't ever been in this pickle! :)  good luck!

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas - No worries. Thank you for taking the time to read and respond!

Comment: @KJ - I attempted this in cmd:

Line 1: echo cd /d "%~1" ^&^& dir /s /b %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 ^>output.lst ^&^& more output.lst>gathers.cmd
Line 2: gathers "I:\" *.doc *.xls *.ppt

Cmd outputs:

cd /d "I:\"     && dir /s /b *.doc *.xls *.ppt

and hangs.

Comment: @KJ - Ah yes. I was simply running it in the cmd window and found after my last comment that it has actually created a file in the same location named output.lst with the discovered file paths. It is however, also finding *.docx *.xlsx *.pptx files, which is not preferred.

Comment: I understand. I added *.doc *.xls *.ppt but it also gets *.docx *.xlsx *.pptx. How can it be made to only get *.doc *.xls *.ppt?

Comment: Unfortunately, the *.do? option results in the same. Anything with "do" in the file extension gets picked up. Thanks for the comments!

Answer (score 0):

Well, its a bit of a hack, but you could do something like

> $files = cmd /c cd  C:\path `& dir /s /b *.exe *.pdf

Found 8k files on my c drive in 17 seconds

Edit:
Asked abut replaceable parameter, this encounters difficulty at first with powershell's reserve of "&"

But can be gotten around...
Make a .cmd file gather.cmd
In this example we have carried the batch file's params out as far as they will go naturally (9). Two things, this allows you to pass 1-8 extensions in, as little as one, as many as eight, if you do not pass the additional ones, the vars end up blank and do not affect execution, and if for some reason you *need* more than 8, it *can* be done but would require some additional code we can explore if this actually does show a speed advantage.

```
@cd %1 & dir /s /b %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

and then call it from powershell using Invoke-Expression.

```
$path = "C:\Users\QUADWORD\Desktop"
$exts = "*.exe *.pdf"
$command = "cmd /c gather.cmd $path $exts"
$output = Invoke-Expression -Command $command
```

Again, this is a hack, but it *may* prove an edge, no way to know without testing, I am actually curious to know on level ground with your tests if better/worse for my own reference.

Comment: I am attempting to implement your suggested solution; however, I am getting no results. Does this method accept variables as input for the path and file extensions? Something like:
$FilePathCollection = cmd /c cd $SourcePath `& dir /s /b $xFilter where $SourcePath = "H:\" and $xFilter = "*.doc *.xls *.ppt"

Comment: I will amend answer.

Comment: I am unsure if the amended response is different. File extensions appear to still be hard-coded in the 'gather.cmd' file. I would like to use a variable (single string or an array of strings holding variable(s)).

Comment: I missed the part where you needed extensions as well. But just as easily done, will amend answer to include those as well. They are done same way as path

Comment: I have a Gather.cmd and Gather.ps1 (both in root of I:\):

Gather.cmd

@cd %1 & dir /s /b %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9

Gather.ps1

$path = "I:\"
$exts = "*.doc *.xls *.ppt"
$command = "cmd /c Gather.cmd $path $exts"
$output = Invoke-Expression -Command $command
Out-GridView $output

I run Gather.ps1 and it hangs.

Comment: There will be a hang as long as the search is running, 8k files took  17 sec on my device, you were estimating numbers much higher, try a smaller search/directory and verify working, otherwise it is the time it is searching most likely.

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell, you can work in the output of a command using [pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines?view=powershell-7.4).

To ensure that Get-ChildItem returns only files, not directories, you can pass it the -File switch parameter.

To make Get-ChildItem return relative file paths insted of FileSystemInfo objects, you can pass it the -Name switch parameter.

Unfortunately, both the -File and the -Name switch parameters make Get-ChildItem slower, so I did not use them in the code sample below.

```
[string]$SourcePath = 'H:\Duplicate File Work\'
[string[]]$IncludeFilter = '*.doc','*.xls','*.ppt'
[string[]]$FilePathCollection = 
    Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $SourcePath -Include $IncludeFilter -Recurse |
    Where-Object -NOT PSIsContainer | # filter out directories
    & { process {
        # Work on a IO.FileInfo object stored in the $_ automatic variable.
        # In this sample, just extract the full path.
        $_.FullName
    } }
```

EnumerateFiles/EnumerateFileSystemEntries could perform better, but not by a huge margin, and at the expense of code readability.

Note that the line `$FilePathCollection += $File` that you included in your question allocates a new array every time an item is added. Collecting items this way will perform very poorly as the number of items grow.